# What is the difference between $ dy $ and $ \Delta y $?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I'm learning to approximate functions using derivatives. I'm a little confused about the notation(s) $ dx $ (or $ dy $) and $ \Delta x $ (or $ \Delta y $). Do they mean the exact same thing -- except for the different curves? In other words, does $ dx $ represent the (small) increase in $ x $ for the straight line given in the image and $ \Delta x $ represent the (small) incrase in $ x $ for the given curve?

Do we use $ dx $ & $ \Delta x  $, and $ dy $ & $\Delta y$ just to differentiate between the increments in the two different function or are they different?

[image]

Why is $ dx $ called the "differential" of $ x $ and $ \Delta x $ being called the "increment" of $ x $ (similarly for y)? My textbook also states:

> We  may  note  that  the differential of the dependent variable is not
>   equal to the increment of the variable where as the differential of
>   independent variable is equal to the increment of the variable

Comment: An increment is a finitely small change while a differential is an infinitely small change.

Comment: Never read theory from NCERT.

Comment: If a finite change $\Delta x$ in $x$ causes a change $\Delta y$ in $y$, then $\frac{dy}{dx}$ is defined as $lim_{\Delta y\rightarrow 0}\frac{\Delta y}{\Delta x}$ —i.e. $\Delta y$ is finite but  $dy$ isn't.

Comment: Putting it another way, $dx$ is (roughly speaking) an infinitely small $\Delta x$.

Comment: Sorry, that should have been $\frac{dy}{dx}=\lim_{\Delta x\rightarrow 0}\frac{\Delta y}{\Delta x}$

Comment: So, what does it mean when someone says $ dx $ = $ \Delta x $ (as given in the text)? How could we compare something infinite with something finite?